# Insert into another table using select query which is nested

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query.

```
 UPDATE A SET A.[a]=A.[a]+C.value
FROM Table A INNER JOIN 
(SELECT ID, STUFF((SELECT ','+P1.value FROM Table P1 WHERE P1.ID=P2.ID AND DATEDIFF(MI,LASTUPDATED,GETUTCDATE()) <=15  FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).VALUE('(./TEXT())[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'') AS alias FROM Table P2 ) P3
ON A.[ID]=P3.ID
```

So I want to insert ID and strings values which is fetched from the select statement in the above query to another table.
I know the way were this objective can be attained i.e.

```
insert into tablename(columns)
select (columns) from table.
```

So I want to incorporate the same thing in my nested query, which hypothetically should look like.

```
 UPDATE A SET A.[a]=A.[a]+C.value
    FROM Table A INNER JOIN 
    (INSERT INTO Tablename(ID,Value)
    (SELECT ID, STUFF((SELECT ','+P1.value FROM Table P1 WHERE P1.ID=P2.ID AND DATEDIFF(MI,LASTUPDATED,GETUTCDATE()) <=15  FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).VALUE('(./TEXT())[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'') AS alias FROM Table P2 )) P3
    ON A.[ID]=P3.ID
```

This is not working in my case. How should I do this

Comment: You won't be able to do an insert while you're doing an update like that. Split the two statements. Update, then insert, or insert, then update. Whichever way you want

Comment: Why is this question tagged [tag:mysql]?  MySQL is an open-source, cross-platform RDBMS now owned by Oracle Corporation that competes against Microsoft's proprietary SQL Server product.  Furthermore, it is not clear from your question exactly what you're trying to accomplish; perhaps some example data before & after would help to illustrate?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do so..

Either insert in a table or update a table. These two queries cant be run as one.

Better choice is to create a stored procedure for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE A SET A.[a]=A.[a]+C.value
FROM Table A

GO

INSERT INTO Tablename(ID,Value
    (SELECT ID, STUFF((SELECT ','+P1.value FROM Table P1 WHERE P1.ID=P2.ID AND DATEDIFF(MI,LASTUPDATED,GETUTCDATE()) <=15  FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).VALUE('(./TEXT())[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'') AS alias FROM Table P2 )) P3
    ON A.[ID]=P3.ID

Answer (score 0):

you can create a trigger driven either from your update or your insert; in this way you will link both events. You need to decide which event triggers the other, depending on your application.